# What scripting languages does Tengine web server support with a default instalation?

Tags: nginx, scripting, webserver

I have installed Tengine webserver from the following location:
http://tengine.taobao.org/

I have created a php page, however PHP does not execute and the PHP is shown in the pages source code within the webpages.

So i am wondering, is their a specific server-side scripting language or coding language such as asp/php that tengine supports by default?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tengine ( an Nginx fork that runs AliBaba and affiliated sites ) supports php but as php-fpm.

Here is a link to start the reader off;

```
https://infinitescript.com/2014/11/build-tengine-mariadb-and-php-on-ubuntu-14-04/
```

Another interesting link:

```
https://www.freelancinggig.com/blog/2018/07/04/what-programming-language-is-alibaba-built-in/
```